# DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute behavior is nearly unpredictable

Tags: c#, .net

I can't figure out how `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` can be used with any certainty. I'll lay out a variety of tests I did on the behavior of the Visual Studio debugger when trying to walk through code using this attribute. `// hit` indicates that the debugger stepped into the code and `// miss` indicates it did not step-in but I feel it should have. I'm sure there is some pattern to the madness but I'm struggling to see it. BTW, running this in a .NET 6 Console app in Visual Studio 17.3.3 (2022 64-bit).

```cs
var test1 = new Test1();
test1.Run();

var test2 = new Test2();
test2.Run();

var test3 = new Test3();
test3.Run();

var test4 = new Test4();
test4.Run();

var test5 = new Test5();
test5.Run();

var test6 = new Test6();
test6.Run();

// Behaves as expected
public class Test1
{
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public void Run()
    {
        A();
        B();
        C();
    }

    void A()
    {
        // hit
    }

    void B()
    {
        // hit
    }

    void C()
    {
        // hit
    }
}

// Returning a value breaks it
public class Test2
{
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public void Run()
    {
        A();
        B();
        C();
    }

    void A()
    {
        // hit
    }

    string B()
    {
        // miss
        return "";
    }

    void C()
    {
        // hit
    }
}

// Adding an argument breaks it
public class Test3
{
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public void Run()
    {
        A();
        B("");
        C();
    }

    void A()
    {
        // hit
    }

    void B(string arg)
    {
        // miss
    }

    void C()
    {
        // hit
    }
}

// Making the first method match argument count fixes it
public class Test4
{
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public void Run()
    {
        A("");
        B("");
        C();
    }

    void A(string arg)
    {
        // hit
    }

    void B(string arg)
    {
        // hit
    }

    void C()
    {
        // hit
    }
}

// Adding another argument breaks it
public class Test5
{
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public void Run()
    {
        A("");
        B("", "");
        C();
    }

    void A(string arg)
    {
        // hit
    }

    void B(string arg, string arg2)
    {
        // miss
    }

    void C()
    {
        // hit
    }
}

// I give up... how can I use this attribute on
// real code if I can barely make sense of it
// in the basic sample set?!
public class Test6
{
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public void Run()
    {
        A("");
        B("", "");
        C();
    }

    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    void A(string arg)
    {
        
    }

    void B(string arg, string arg2)
    {
        // hit
    }

    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    void C()
    {
        
    }
}
```